# Is there any python library for searching specific words like "the", "is", "was", "am" .... and other similar words?

Tags: python, nlp, open-source, pypi

I want to exclude such words from a text file. Currently, my code just counts the occurrences of all the words in the text file, but I want to exclude such unwanted words as mentioned before and only count the frequency of certain important words. There are many important words in the file so I cannot include all of them. So it would be helpful  if there was a preexisting library in python

Comment: nltk has predefined lists of stop words.

Comment: why dont you clean the text by excluding specific words and then do a counter returning word frequency?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I will look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such words are called stop words, you can easily remove them by using the [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/) library

```py
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
# print(list(stopwords.words('english')))
filtered_words = [word for word in word_list if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
```